# BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator on DataFlowRunner keeps throwing error missing service_account

Tags: python

I am running  following DataFlow config

```
test_dataflow= BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator(
    task_id="xxxx", 
    runner="DataflowRunner", 
    py_file=xxxxx,
    pipeline_options = dataflow_options,
    py_requirements=['apache-beam[gcp]==2.39.0'],
    py_interpreter='python3',
    dataflow_config=DataflowConfiguration(job_name="{{task.task_id}}", location=LOCATION, project_id=PROJECT, wait_until_finished=False,gcp_conn_id="google_cloud_default")
    #dataflow_config={"job_name":"{{task.task_id}}", "location":LOCATION, "project_id":PROJECT, "wait_until_finished":True,"gcp_conn_id":"google_cloud_default"}
)
```

It keeps throwing error . airflow-2.2.5 version.

```
Error - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/beam/operators/beam.py", line 287, in execute
    ) = self._init_pipeline_options(format_pipeline_options=True, job_name_variable_key="job_name")
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/beam/operators/beam.py", line 183, in _init_pipeline_options
    dataflow_job_name, pipeline_options, process_line_callback = self._set_dataflow(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/beam/operators/beam.py", line 63, in _set_dataflow
    pipeline_options = self.__get_dataflow_pipeline_options(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/beam/operators/beam.py", line 92, in __get_dataflow_pipeline_options
    if self.dataflow_config.service_account:
AttributeError: 'DataflowConfiguration' object has no attribute 'service_account'
```

If I give service_account, then it errors saying parameter invalid

Comment: Please help anyone

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.

This is because of the inconsistency between the dataflow_configuration in dataflow and the one expected by beam. The DataflowConfiguration doesn't accepting the service_account.

I resolved my issue by upgrading the composer in place, so it gets the latest package related to dataflow where it has been fixed.

The service_account attribute has been added in this commit https://github.com/apache/airflow/commit/de65a5cc5acaa1fc87ae8f65d367e101034294a6

If you can't upgrade composer, try updating the google providers package to the latest version or > version 7.0 ?

You can check the commit in the commit log and identify the minimum version here - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/commits.html#id6

Even though composer uses it's own fork, the oss should work. You can see the list of packages in the composer version list https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions it says apache-airflow-providers-google==2022.5.18+composer instead of apache-airflow-providers-google==7.0.